# GenICam::gcstring from int

Tags: c++, string

I am using Pylon library from Basler, an extension of GenICam.

There they have defined a function for saving an image as:

```
virtual void Save (EImageFileFormat imageFileFormat, const String_t &filename, CImagePersistenceOptions *pOptions=NULL) const
```

Where String_t is an extension of GenICam::gcstring

The information about gcstring is below:

---

```
Portable string implementation. More...
#include <new>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Base/GCTypes.h>
Classes
class   GenICam::gcstring
    A string class which is a clone of std::string. More...

Namespaces
    GenICam
    Contains definitions of GenICam types and exceptions.

Macros
#define     GCSTRING_NPOS   size_t(-1)
    Indicates either 'not found' or 'all remaining characters'.

Functions
std::istream &  GenICam::getline (std::istream &is, GenICam::gcstring &str)

std::istream &  GenICam::getline (std::istream &is, GenICam::gcstring &str, char delim)

std::ostream &  operator<< (std::ostream &ostr, const GenICam::gcstring &str)

std::istream &  operator>> (std::istream &istr, GenICam::gcstring &str)
```

---

I need to save an image with a filename generated from a long int and I've tried so many ways but failed, anyone who can help?

Comment: @user19703081 check out the Basler documentation. you could use openCV to save the image instead of using the built in function. check out page 9 in this document [HERE](http://s.baslerweb.com/media/documents/AW00136801000_Getting_Started_with_pylon5_and_OpenCV.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still looking for an answer, String_t accepts a const char array as an input. So you can simply convert your `long` to an `std::string` and then pass in `string.c_str()` to the `String_t` constructor.

So to convert from long to `std::string` do this:

```
#include <string> 

long myNumber = getNumber();
std::string s = std::to_string(myNumber);
```

Then you can save the image like so:

```
CImagePersistence::Save(ImageFileFormat_Tiff, String_t(s.c_str()), *image);
```

Note: I'm using pylon 5.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below method.

```
char char_arr [100];
long int num = 10;
sprintf(char_arr, "%d", num);
String_t stringValue(char_arr);
```